# How to set up friends as recipients in public activity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have set up a friendship model for my app,

```
create_table "friendships", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id"
  t.integer  "friend_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

And the model looks like this,

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

And this is my user model,

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

And I have tracked my movie model with the Public Activity gem,

```
include PublicActivity::Model
tracked owner: -> (controller, model) { controller && controller.current_user }
tracked :params => {
  :title => :get_title,
  :poster => :get_poster
}

has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

The current situation is that when a user adds a activity to the app, every other user sees that notificiation. What I would like is to only send the activity to the friends of the user.

I think all the necessary data and links are preset, but I'm unsure on how to hook it all up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to do this through [custom activity](https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity#create-custom-activities/).
For example,

When a new movie is created , you can do the create activity a callback method,

```
after_create :create_activity

def create_activity
   user.friends.each do |friend|
      self.create_activity action: :new , parameters: {title:title,poster:poster}, recipient: friend, owner: current_user
  end
end
```

however this solution is very inefficient. I am not sure if there is a method provided for the gem that you can create multiple activities all together, like ActiveRecord, Moview.create([{title:1},{title:2}]). Otherwise you many want to move this into a background job, something like [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) .

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it doesn't seem to do the trick. Both `friend` and `friends` give a NoMethodError  `NoMethodError (undefined method `friend' for #<Movie:0x007fd941206120>):
  app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:19:in `create'
`

Comment: Hi @PeterBoomsma. Please try updated answer. I think you need to define the association btw movie/friend also.

Comment: I've put the above code in my movie model and although I'm not getting a error when I create a new activity the `"recipient_id":null,"recipient_type":null` are still `null`

Comment: Hey @PeterBoomsma sorry I think I misunderstood what you wanted to do. I've updated my answer. I personally can't  think of  a built in way to achieve that reading their documentation. I think the solution can be somewhat in the lines of what the updated answer is, but be warned it is not the best way. And let me know if you find a better way!